# "Apologies from my end" Vs "apologies from my part"

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is it correct/idiomatic to say "apologies from my end"? For example, "apologies from my end, the reason you couldn't do it was because I forgot to grant your account the right permissions".

I think apologies "from my part" would be kosher, but I'm not sure whether "from my end" sounds natural or is correct.

Comment: It's _on my part_, not _from_.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your proposed forms sound like attempts to distance oneself from the offered apology.
You can just say, very simply, "My apologies,..." or "I apologize.", followed by an explanation of the apology.

Comment: Thanks! But I think I've heard this before, though I'm not sure, and I was wondering whether it's usual to say something like "apologies from my end". I thought this could also be more or less similar to "that's on me" instead of distancing oneself from the apology

Comment: @flen - *My apologies* means *that's on me.*  If you were apologizing on behalf of another person you would say something like, *I apologize for Hugo's behavior.*